# CodeReady Containers: developer doesn't have permissions to see the Topology

Tags: permissions, installation, openshift

In ***layman's/beginner's*** terms, how do you give the developer permissions to the Topology section and whatever else they need, to perform general development with CodeReady Containers, as described in the instructions?

---

I'm looking into using OpenShift, which initially looked promising.  However Minishift and CodeReady Containers have both had issues working on my Windows machine, so now I'm trying to use CodeReady Containers on a Cent OS system.

After setting up CRC and opening the console in Firefox, I select the `htpasswrd_provider` option and log in as `developer`/`developer`, which is exactly what Red Hat's instructions/tutorials say to do.  And as they recommend, I created a new project, then switched to the Developer view and tried going into the Topology section.

There I get this error:

```
deploymentconfigs.apps.openshift.io is forbidden: User "developer" cannot list resource "deploymentconfigs" in API group "apps.openshift.io" in the namespace "default"
```

*Rolls eyes.*  This is contrary to their own directions.  Furthermore Red Shift's tutorials act like the developer is initially the only user available, although the username itself can be `admin`, `developer`, or whatever else you want it to be.  So this user really just needs to be able to work.

On a personal note, I have spent a lot of time researching containers and container orchestration the last few months, having come from a Windows/.NET background, and I am sick and tired of every "simplification" of Kubernetes and other, related technologies failing to work as described, having to be troubleshot and "repaired" straight out of the box.  I have Googled this, but have spent enough time sifting through haystacks troubleshooting issues like this, and to some extent, I feel like this software and/or its documentation is just broken.

*In **layman's/beginner's** terms, how do you give the developer permissions to the Topology section and whatever else they need, to perform general development with CodeReady Containers, as described in the instructions?*